# C++17 - Binding rvalue reference to non-const lvalue ref

Tags: c++, c++17

I did a quick look through the C++17 Standard but I couldn't quite figure out how the following code somehow compiles when using `-std=c++17` in both Clang and GCC.

It does NOT compile, however, if `-std=c++17` is not set, as I expected.

The way I see it, the code calls the copy constructor of `Test`, which has a non-const lvalue reference as parameter using an rvalue reference on line 21. This will attempt to bind the rvalue reference to the lvalue reference, which (as far as I know) is not allowed.

```
#include<iostream> 

class Test 
{ 
public: 
   Test()        { std::cout << "Test()\n";  } 
   // Copy constructor with non-const parameter
   Test(Test &t) { std::cout << "Test(Test&)\n"; } 
}; 

Test fun() 
{ 
    std::cout << "fun() called\n"; 
    Test t; 
    return t; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    Test t1; 
    Test t2 = fun(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

What changed on C++17 that allowed this program to compile successfully?

Tested on Compiler Explorer with both Clang and GCC (latest versions): <kbd>[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/O8h6qk)</kbd>

Link for the non-c++17 version (which does not compile): <kbd>[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/yLsOG1)</kbd>

Comment: Guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: @gsamaras Compiler Explorer does have line numbers though.

Comment: Also, tyvm @T.C.